# Python subprocess for queries with quotes

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to fire this query which runs perfectly on the terminal:

```
sed -i '' '/default\]/a\'$'\n''  Hello world'$'\n' <PATH_TO_FILE>
```

This adds a line below where I find "default]" string.

Using the python code:

```
query = r""" sed -i '' '/default\]/a\'$'\n''  Hello world'$'\n' %s """ % (PATH_T)_FILE)
proc = subprocess.Popen(query.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err =  proc.communicate()
```

However, the command fails in python with error:

```
Error executing the query  sed -i '' '/default\]/a\'$'\n''  Hello world'$'\n' /Users/hshah/tmpFile . output = , error = sed: 1: "'/default\]/a\'$'\n''": invalid command code '
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: The first line defining `query` is not valid Python code.

Comment: @FullName Right; probably `(PATH_T)_FILE)` should be `(PATH_TO_FILE)`. I wonder why someone would type the code here instead of copy/pasting…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `split`  on *every*  whitespace. This causes `query.split()` to be

```
['sed',
 '-i',
 "''",
 "'/default\\]/a\\'$'\\n''",
 'Hello',
 "world'$'\\n'",
 '/tmp/foo']
```

which is not what you want. Build up the parameters for `subprocess.Popen`  by hand, not by splitting a string.

Comment: BTW, the parameters for `Popen` would be `['sed', '-i', '', '/default\]/a\n', 'Hello world\n', PATH_TO_FILE]`.